# How to count element from belogsToMany relation [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

Here is my relation:

```
public function commentsCount(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment','project_comment');
}
```

I am trying to get acount of all comments...

Here is my query

```
 $count = Project::with(['commentsCount' => function($q) {
                    $q->where('project_id', $this->id);
            }, 'groups' => function($q) {
                $q->where('project_id', $this->id)->where('user_id', Auth::id());
            }])->where('id', $this->id)->get();
```

Any solution?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$projects = Project::with('commentsCount')->get();

foreach($projects as $project){
    echo $project->commentsCount()->count()
}
```

OR

```
public function commentsCount(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment','project_comment')->count();
}

$projects = Project::with('commentsCount')->get();

foreach($projects as $project){
    echo $project->commentsCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
 $projects= Project::with('commentsCount','groups') 
         ->where('id', $this->id)->first();
 $comments_count = $projects -> commentsCount -> count();
```